# Add TL Symbol to Character Viewer (Unicode 20BA) [TL simgesi]

Tags: macos, font, internationalization, unicode

I want to add the new 2012 Turkish Lira currency symbol, U+20BA, to Character Viewer as shown at

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_lira_sign

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a reference to a font which will give you the character you are looking for in Character Viewer

http://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2012/05/font-with-new-turkish-lira-symbol.html

You may need to deactivate some other font if that has an interfering character -- I had one called PT on my machine.

Answer (score -1):

option+T makes the ₺ symbol if you have your keyboard set to Turkish - QWERTY PC